# Add Timeout / Sleep function inside javascript loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to add a sleep / delay function inside a js file, This one:

```
var webTest = function()
{

let regex = /^https?:\/\//;
let url = $('#list_urls').val().split('\n');
var xmlhttp = [], i;
var myObj2 = [], i;
 for(let i = 0; i < url.length; i++)
    {
    (function(i) {
    xmlhttp[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
    url[i] = url[i].replace(regex, '');
    xmlhttp[i].open("GET", "https://website.com/API?key=<MY_API_KEY>&url="+url[i], false);
    xmlhttp[i].onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp[i].readyState === 4 && xmlhttp[i].status === 200) {
        myObj2 = JSON.parse(xmlhttp[i].responseText);
        document.getElementById("demo"+i).innerHTML = myObj2.results[1].categories;
      }
    };
xmlhttp[i].send();
})(i);
console.log(`The Server2: `+ myObj2);
 }
}
```

I want this script to pause for 10 second and then again do work and then again pause for 10 second and do like this untill text length is greater thatn **i** in loop! My code works if i run for single time but it doesn't works if i run in loop because the **website** has rate limit in the **api** so that's why i'm trying to add a sleep function.

So what i've tried is **await sleep();** method and also tried **setTimeout** method but it's not working as expected in sort it doesn't works at all with my code!

await sleep(); just doesn't works at all and displays msg like
**Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async generators webTestfile.js:27**

Comment: *I want this script to pause for 10 second and then again do work and then again pause for 10 second!* You cannot pause code. What you can do is run more code after a delay, but the currently running function on the call stack must complete before any new code can start.

Comment: Yeah i know that javascript doesn't have any sleep functionality but what can be done here to achieve at least 10-11second delay? tried setTimeout method but nothing worked :/

Comment: This answer shows a [`sleep()`-alternative for JS in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/13561410).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [make use of ES6's `async/await`-feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/13561410)!

To use `await`, it needs to be in a function/expression body declared `async`.

Basically, this will make your function be asynchronous, and make it wait for a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to be fulfilled. We make that Promise be fulfilled after a set delay using `setTimeout()`.
**Note** that "after a set delay" does not mean "exactly after", it basically means "as early as possible after".

By doing this, the asynchronous function waits for the promise to be fulfilled, freeing up the callstack in the meantime so that other code can be executed.

The order of execution of this example is (simplified) as follows:

1. `sleepingFunc()` is placed on callstack

   - In iteration: `await` for Promise to be fulfilled, suspending this call  freeing up callstack
2. Place new calls on callstack
3. Eventually, Promise is fulfilled, ending `await`  place suspended call back on callstack
4. Repeat until `sleepingFunc()` finished

As you can see in step 3, if other calls take up more time than the delay, the suspended call will have to wait that extra time longer.

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolveFunc => setTimeout(resolveFunc, ms));
}

async function sleepingFunc() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    console.log(i + " - from sleep");
    await sleep(1000);
  }
}

function synchronousFunc() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    console.log(i + " - from sync");
  }
}

sleepingFunc();
synchronousFunc();
```

Answer (score 2):

This runs snippet runs one task every 1 second until the condition is satisfied, and then clears the timer.

```js
const work = (i)=>{
 console.log('doing work here ', i);
}

let counter = 0
const timer = setInterval(()=>{
  if (timer && ++counter >= 10) {
   clearInterval(timer)
  }
  work(counter);
}, 1000)
```