# JavaScript Gradually Slowing Motion Not Working Properly:

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

The code below should move the element "box" down by "speed" pixels every second, and "speed" should decrease by 0.1 every second. This should give the illusion of slowing movement. If anyone knows how to fix this code - or offer a different solution - it would be greatly appreciated.

```
function move() {
    var pos = 318;
    
    for (var speed = 5; speed > 0; speed -= 0.1) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            pos -= speed;
            document.getElementById("box").style.bottom = pos + "px";
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could we see the `HTML` part of your code as well? Perhaps create a snippet.

Comment: The setTimeout doesn't seem to delay the for loop, instead after one second the box gets moved several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setTimeout inside the for loop doesn't actually create a delay between iterations as you'd expect, rather it simply does all of the function executions after one second. Instead, you should create another function inside the `move()` function that calls itself with `setTimeout()`, or use `setInterval()`.

Using setTimeout:

```js
function move() {
    var pos = 0;
    
    var speed = 5;
    function moveBox() {
      if (speed <= 0) {console.log("done"); return;}
      speed -= 0.1;
      pos += speed; // done backwards for visibility
      document.getElementById("box").style.top = pos + "px";
      setTimeout(moveBox, 25) //sped up for convenience
    }
    moveBox();
}
move();
```

```css
#box {
  position: absolute;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" style="bottom: 318px"></div>
```

Comment: Do you know about the "new" way to make a [`sleep()` function in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64996707/13561410)?   
It's easier to read, and can easily be used without providing a callback.